my anchorlayout won't anchor to the position I set
So, I want to anchor the "Owner's Name" label to the center top of this yellow layout. Here is my code :
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.anchorlayout import MDAnchorLayout
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.metrics import sp

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen(md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#CDE2FF"))

        layout_title = MDAnchorLayout(
            anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom',
            radius = [25, 25, 25, 25],
            md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#FFF000"),
            size_hint = (0.5, 0.5),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.325, "center_y": 0.7},
        )

        layout = MDFloatLayout(
            radius = [25, 25, 25, 25],
            md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#FFF9E6"),
            size_hint = (0.85, 0.6),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        )

        LabelBase.register(
            name="font50",
            fn_regular="font50.ttf"
        )

        self.theme_cls.font_styles["font50"] = {
            "large": {
                "line-height": 1.64,
                "font-name": "font50",
                "font-size": sp(50)
            }
        }

        label_title = MDLabel(
            text = "Owner's Information",
            font_style = "font50"
            )

        layout_title.add_widget(label_title)
        screen.add_widget(layout)
        screen.add_widget(layout_title)

        return screen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()

I already set the anchor, but it won't anchor. Is there something that I do wrong here? I already tried to set the size_hint to None, it works but it made each character on the Label text disjointed (? like not in the same line) or I have to set the size really small in order for the character on the Label text to be in a same line.


You should wrap your anchor layout first to your float layout.
layout.add_widget(layout_title)

Then:
layout_title.add_widget(label_title)
screen.add_widget(layout)

And also to your layout title pos_hint={"center_x": 0.325, "center_y": 0.7} is unnecessary since you're already using anchor layout.
